# Explain why $1 < \frac{c}{p} < c$ where $c$ is a composite number and $p$ is a prime number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Explain why $1 < \frac{c}{p} < c$ where $c$ is a composite number and $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: That is not correct if $c=6$ and $p=11$

Comment: In your source I assume $p$ is supposed to be a prime divisor of $c$. Then it's true and not hard to see. Try it out on some examples, say $c = 12$ and $p = 2, 3$.

Comment: Nothing to do with prime and composite.  $p > 1$ then $\frac cp<\frac c1 < c$.  And if $p < c$ then $1= \frac pp < \frac cp$.  That's all.

Comment: Hint: the inequality is equivalent to $\ 1 < p < c,\ $ so it holds for $\,p\,$ being any proper factor of $\,c,\,$ not only prime factors.

Comment: The problem clearly states (in the book) that p is the smallest prime divisor of c.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions.

Comment: BTW, if you have too many poorly received questions the system will automatically ban you from asking new questions. Deleted questions are included in the ban algorithm calculation, so deleting such questions does *not* protect you from that ban. Instead, you need to try to fix the bad questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, I assume, that $p$ is a prime factor of a composite number $c$.

That means, by definition of being a factor, that $\frac cp$ is an integer.  And because $c$ is composite and $p$ is prime this means $p$ isn't the only factor and $\frac cp \ne 1$.

I assume that is the issue the book is trying to get across.  That $1 < \frac cp < c$ is trivial and obvious.

As $c$ and $p$ are positive and $p$ divides $c$ and $c$ is composite and $p$ is prime we know that $\frac cp$ is a positive integer that is not equal to $1$.  So $1 < \frac cp$.

And as $p > 1$ we know that $\frac cp < \frac c1 = c$.

So that's it.  $1 < \frac cp < c$.

Although the book is talking about integers and factoring; it will always be the case for *any* type of real numbers that if $0 < w < v$ and $1 < v$ that $1 < \frac wv < w$.

(And if $p > c$ [so $p$ *isn't* a factor of $c$] the result is not true.)